# Table schema to store text id coming from a third party API

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm collecting data from a third party API with the following format:

Items:

```
item_id : 'RSA24334343',
site_code : 'RSA',
name: 'Mouse'
```

Categories:

```
category_id: 'RSA3232',
site_code : 'RSA',
name: 'Electronics',
parent_id: 'RSA1122'
```

So what I first thought was defining the tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
category_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
site_code text,
name text,
parent_id text --REFERENCES category
);

CREATE TABLE item(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id integer REFERENCES category,
    site_code text,
    name text
);
```

But storing them with integer id's would require some extra code before doing something with the data. I could create a dictionary in python like:

```
SITE_CODES = {'RSA': 0, 'RSB': 1}
```

And then replacing the 'RSA' in the item id with the new integer value but I think that would be troublesome and I don't really like it.

I could use the complete item_id, store and index it as text, but I don't really if that's the best choice in terms of performance. The db will be used for heavy querying and the db size will grow quickly. This is a simplified version, but there are some extra tables with similar issues.

I'd like to know which way to take maximizing for performance.

Comment: `parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES category(category_id)` and  `category_id integer REFERENCES category(category_id)` BTW: in item: `site_code text,` looks redundant to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short text field isn't going to be significantly slower than an integer field.  This is an area of "over optimization". Just consider the ramifications of everything you're doing from a programming standpoint-- don't consider performance of the key type, consider the mental/programming overhead of whatever solution you come up with. For my DBA brain, if there's a single column primary key of reasonable size, and you don't need to generate these keys yourself-- allow the incoming data to determine the key type and rock on down the road. You'll forget about that decision in no time, as it'll just work without a lot of extra overhead.

Comment: Thanks, what would you consider as a "short text field"?

Comment: I go with 40 characters, and It's fairly arbitrary, but beyond 40, I start looking more into the situation (volume of data, foreign keys, etc)-- beyond 255 characters, I wouldn't use it.